# What does it mean to omit the <version> element in a Maven <dependency>?

Tags: maven

In a `pom.xml` I have:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
    <artifactId>bar</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

There is no `<version>` element. But when I run this:

```
> mvn dependency:list
...
[INFO]    com.foo:bar:jar:1.2.3.RELEASE:compile
```

it gives me a version, i.e. `1.2.3.RELEASE`.

**What rules did Maven follow to determine that version? What does it mean to omit the `<version>` element?**

Comment: @lexicore maybe -- though that question is much less clear, and it's unanswered. Also, I do not have a `<dependencyManagement>` section that defines the version.

Comment: It is answered twice, but for some reason none of the answers is accepted. Please check the answer by coderplus, you probably have it in the parent pom somewhere.

Comment: Oh -- apparently the version is managed by a `<dependencyManagement>` section for a different dependency, which in turn has a `<dependencyManagement>` section that defines the version for `bar`. Crazy. Thanks.

Comment: This does not sound good to me. Should not be. Only parents should count. Run `mvn -X dependency:tree`.

Comment: @lexicore for concreteness, the module is `spring-framework-bom`. Apparently that's the way it's designed.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In a `<dependencyManagement>` section I was including a module which defined the version of `bar` in its `<dependencyManagement>` section, i.e. my `pom.xml` looks like:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
            <artifactId>qux</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
    <artifactId>bar</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and the `pom.xml` for the included module `qux` at version `1.2.3.RELEASE` looks like:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
            <artifactId>baz</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Apparently, `<dependencyManagement>` sections are transitive, so the version defined for `baz` in that module gets transcluded into my own module.

Comment: what you replied only meaningful to yourself.